# As location changes Restaurant list should change automatically without a button click app

Tags: android, location

I am designing an android app where I want to list all the restaurants in a particular location. This happens on the launch of the app.
As the location changes, the list of restaurants should change accordingly even if the app is already opened.
Whatever examples I got on google do this populating of restaurants on the click of a button. But in my case it happens on the launch and if app is already launched then also depending on the location the list should change itself.

I have made a MainClass under which there is a subclass of AsyncTask and this subclass has a class which implements LocationListener.
But problem is this I have to call doInBackground() method again in onLocationChange to get the results automatically when location gets changed.

Please guide me what should I do?

Comment: Please post code samples with your post, and describe which part of it is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Put all the logic you have for obtaining the user location and gathering new restaurant data into a `Service`.  The `Service` can listen for your location updates (which hopefully are set to sparse interval if you want it running all the time) and then update the list with your `AsyncTask` whenever a significant enough change that requires new data occurs.

You can bind to the `Service` in an `Activity` when it's in the foreground (between `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods) to get the latest information and register as a callback  if the data updates during the period while the `Activity` is visible to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your list.

You can read more about creating a `Service` bound locally in your application [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binder).

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use some ArrayAdapter for the restaurants list and save it's instance in the Main class, then whenever the location changed use the AsyncTask to retreive the nearby restaurants and `onPostExecute` replace the ArrayAdapter internal list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to location changes in your main class. Upon receiving a (significant) change start an asynctask to query the restaurants. Pass the results (e.g. array of restaurants) to onPostExecute and update your UI accordingly.

Maybe disable updates while restaurants are being queried or cancel the query and start a new one on each new update.